# element with overflow:hidden still has it's full width

Tags: html, css

If you run the snippet below, everything looks like it's working. But if you inspect the text within the border in your dev-tools, and hover over the element you'll see the width of the text is still full length. This is a problem when trying to make that container responsive. How can I hide the overflow, and use `text-overflow: ellipsis` while having it's width be representative of what we see?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">
    <a>
      looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text
    </a>
  </span>
  <button>hello</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `<span>` and add the `.text` class to your `<a>` tag. Your CSS was not applied to your text because of the `<a>` tags

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="text">
      looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text
    </a>
  <button>hello</button>
</div>
```